# DragGesture breaking sheet's swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, gesture

I'm experiencing a problem where if I add a DragGesture to a whole view that is supposed to be presented as a sheet modal than the default behavior of dismissing the sheet by dragging it doesn't work. Here's an example code I wrote up to demonstrate this bug:

```
private extension UIApplication {
    func dismissFirstResponder() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

struct DragGestureExample: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            VStack(alignment: .center){
                TextField("Type Text Here", text: .constant(""))
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
                Text("Hello, World!")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { _ in
                    UIApplication.shared.dismissFirstResponder()
                })
    }
}
```

And here's my ContentView that calls the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShown: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Click for sheet") {
                self.isShown.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShown) {
                DragGestureExample()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The drag gesture to dismiss the keyboard works, however it breaks the default drag behavior of the sheet. If I remove the drag gesture then I am able to drag to dismiss the sheet again. Is there anyway to give priority to the sheet's gesture?

Answer (score 0):

Your **DragGestureExample** is taking all screen of **sheet**, So **sheet** is going to background as itself, and since you are given a DragGesture to your all screen of **DragGestureExample**, then there is no more job to do for sheet drag dismiss functionality because you are using it for your own code!
There is way you can have both! You can put dismiss sheet code on DragGesture of **DragGestureExample** in your logic you like, then you can use both drag again!

For Example after you dismiss the keyboard or your special jobs, then put a condition for dismissing sheet as well, for example if transition is greater than some value then dismiss the sheet! or even offset first then completely dismiss it.